# How do I create a calendar for setting appointments for a barbershop?

Tags: mysql

I have a barbers table (barberId, first name, last name)
I have a clientele table (clientId, first name, last name)

The barbershop is by appointment only. What tables do I need to create a system where clients can look at a calendar, see which barbers are available, and set appointment with a barber?

The barbers don't have a set schedule: a barber may have a few hours here and there. Therefore a client must look in the calendar to see availability.

I am using MySQL.

Comment: If the business day-to-day work won't support this feature, then why the application should? Note: if there's the compromise that the barbers will do, then ask for a sheet with 2 or 3 people schedule and design the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many ways for doing this and it depends on your business requirements. First I would rename `clientele` to just `clients` it will be easier to work with, easier pluralization when you set variables and so on.

If a barber has 3 hours available, does it mean 3 appointments of 1 hour? What if a certain client needs 2 hours? What would happen in this scenario?

Let's assume that each one takes 1 hour. You can create a table called `appointments`, with `appointment_id, barber_id, client_id, start_time, end_time`. Appointments can be created by barbers or managers, client_id is set when appointment is booked. If you want to see available slots, you will query DB for any appointment that meets `start_time, end_time` requirements and doesn't have a `client_id`. You can filter by a specific `barber_id` or show all available times and their respective barbers.

Comment: I really like your answer. My original `appointments` table was missing the clientId. So many thanks (up vote).  But here is a problem. Say a barber will be available from 9a to 2p and then from 3p to 9p. Say each hair cut can last any where from 30min to 2hours -- in half hour increments. So, for the barber's 9a to 2p slot, do I have 10 entries (half hour blocks) for that timespan? Isn't that too many rows for just one barber for the first half of his day?

Comment: Not really, number of rows is not a real problem. Do clients signup for an appointment themselves or do they have to call and have someone create an appointment for them? What's the lifecycle of this data, do you need to keep all appointments that were completed?

Comment: You can also create a schedule concept, each barber would have 1 or several blocks per day of available time, and appointments then will have to fit into that time span AND not to overlap other appointments, this way you might not have to generate time slots ahead of time. You will have a 9am-3pm block, with 9am-10am 11:30-12:00PM etc appointments that will fit inside of it. so when you create new one, query will check if it fits into 9am-3pm, and if it is taken by any other appointment.